# How to import Chinese font SimSun on overleaf?

Tags: fonts, xetex, overleaf

I am trying to use Chinese font `simsun` on the overleaf. but it gave me an error.

Firstly, I tried this solution, but it is not working.

```
\setCJKfamilyfont{zhsong}[AutoFakeBold = {4.27}]{SimSun}
\renewcommand*{\songti}{\CJKfamily{zhsong}}
```

I also use `KaiTi` font which is working fine.

```
\setCJKfamilyfont{zhkai}[AutoFakeBold = {4.27}]{KaiTi}
\renewcommand*{\kaishu}{\CJKfamily{zhkai}}
```

Then I found out a list of the CJK Chinese fonts which are available on overleaf from https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Which_OTF_or_TTF_fonts_are_supported_via_fontspec%3F#Chinese

Then I upload `SimSun.ttf` in Overleaf and import from the uploaded font.

```
\setCJKmainfont{zhsong}[AutoFakeBold = {4.27}]{SimSun.ttf}
\renewcommand*{\songti}{\CJKfamily{zhsong}}
```

But I got these errors:

`Package fontspec Error: The font "zhsong" cannot be found.`

```
‪./thesis.cls, 160‬
For immediate help type H <return>.
...                                              
                                                 
l.160 ...JKmainfont{zhsong}[AutoFakeBold = {4.27}]{SimSun.ttf}

A font might not be found for many reasons.
Check the spelling, where the font is installed, etc. etc.
```

Comment: The font file of `中易宋体` is `simsun.ttc` not `SimSun.ttf`. You just put `simsun.ttc` in the same folder of `.tex` file. And use it by file name not font name, such as `\setCJKmainfont{simsun.ttc}[AutoFakeBold]`. I suggest you read the doc of `xeCJK`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked with `\setCJKmainfont{simsun.ttc}`

Comment: BTW, questions like these are perfect requests for the Overleaf support ;-)

Comment: @MS-SPO But the main issue with OP is the incorrect use of the `\setCJKmainfont` command provided by the `xeCJK` package.